# Best way to load a Pillow Image object from binary data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, png

I have a program that modifies PNG files with Python's Pillow library. I was wondering how I could load binary data into a PNG image from PIL's Image object. I receive the PNG over a network as binary data (e.g. the data looks like b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR...'). What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest receiving the data into a `BytesIO` object from the `io` standard library package. You can then treat that as a file-like object for the purposes of Pillow.